# Avoiding segfault upon entering pdb in exception in multithreaded PyQt5 application?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, pdb

The below code `test-mt-pyqt5.py` is taken from https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/ ; what it does, is that it shows a counter in the GUI (controlled by a thread), and then there is a "danger" button, which starts another thread, which prints a progress in the terminal.

[image: gui]

Now, I have tried to trigger an exception in the `progress_fn` function (by trying to access an empty list), which runs when the "danger" button is pressed - and then I try to enter `pdb` debugger at that point, so I can debug the problem.

The tricky part is, when I run this in MSYS2 (rather, MINGW64) Python3 on Windows, everything works as expected:

```
$ python3 test-mt-pyqt5.py
Python version: 3.8.7 (default, Jan  7 2021, 11:10:13)  [GCC 10.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version info: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=7, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Qt version: 5.15.0
PyQt version: 331520
Multithreading with maximum 8 threads
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-mt-pyqt5.py", line 93, in progress_fn
    testtrig = a[idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
> c:/msys64/tmp/test-mt-pyqt5.py(102)progress_fn()
-> print("%d%% done" % n)
p idx
0
quit()
```

However, when I try the same on Raspberry Pi Raspbian Stretch, I get a segfault:

```
$ python3 test-mt-pyqt5.py 
Python version: 3.5.3 (default, Jul  9 2020, 13:00:10) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
Version info: sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Qt version: 5.7.1
PyQt version: 329472
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
Multithreading with maximum 4 threads
inotify_add_watch("/home/pi/.config/qt5ct") failed: "No such file or directory"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-mt-pyqt5.py", line 93, in progress_fn
    testtrig = a[idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
Segmentation fault
```

Would anyone have any idea, how can I drop into pdb upon exception in a multithreaded PyQt5 application in Raspbian Stretch in this context, without triggering a segmentation fault?

Here is the code:

`test-mt-pyqt5.py`:

```py
# example from https://www.learnpyqt.com/tutorials/multithreading-pyqt-applications-qthreadpool/

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import time
import traceback, sys

from PyQt5 import Qt
print("Python version: {}".format(sys.version))
print("Version info: {}".format(sys.version_info))
print("Qt version:", Qt.QT_VERSION_STR)
print("PyQt version:", Qt.PYQT_VERSION)

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
  finished = pyqtSignal()
  error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
  result = pyqtSignal(object)
  progress = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QRunnable):
  def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Worker, self).__init__()

    # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
    self.fn = fn
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    # Add the callback to our kwargs
    self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

  @pyqtSlot()
  def run(self):
    '''
    Initialise the runner function with passed args, kwargs.
    '''

    # Retrieve args/kwargs here; and fire processing using them
    try:
      result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    except:
      traceback.print_exc()
      exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
      self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
    else:
      self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
    finally:
      self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.counter = 0

    layout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.l = QLabel("Start")
    b = QPushButton("DANGER!")
    b.pressed.connect(self.oh_no)

    layout.addWidget(self.l)
    layout.addWidget(b)

    w = QWidget()
    w.setLayout(layout)

    self.setCentralWidget(w)

    self.show()

    self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
    print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

    self.timer = QTimer()
    self.timer.setInterval(1000)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.recurring_timer)
    self.timer.start()

  def progress_fn(self, n):
    # trigger exception deliberately here
    a = []
    idx = 0
    try:
      testtrig = a[idx]
    except:
      from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtRemoveInputHook
      import pdb, traceback
      pyqtRemoveInputHook()
      extype, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
      traceback.print_exc()
      #pdb.post_mortem(tb)
      pdb.set_trace()
    print("%d%% done" % n)

  def execute_this_fn(self, progress_callback):
    for n in range(0, 5):
      time.sleep(1)
      progress_callback.emit(int(n*100/4))

    return "Done."

  def print_output(self, s):
    print(s)

  def thread_complete(self):
    print("THREAD COMPLETE!")

  def oh_no(self):
    # Pass the function to execute
    worker = Worker(self.execute_this_fn) # Any other args, kwargs are passed to the run function
    worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output)
    worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)
    worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn)

    # Execute
    self.threadpool.start(worker)


  def recurring_timer(self):
    self.counter +=1
    self.l.setText("Counter: %d" % self.counter)


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Have you tried using the same version of PyQt5 on your Desktop? Since I see that you use 5.15.0 and in the other 5.7.1. I have tested it on Linux (not RPi) with PyQt 5.15.0 and I see the same as on your Windows

Comment: It could also be the different version of python, I just tested it with python 3.9.0

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc - indeed, it looks like the problem is due to different versions of Python/PyQt5; I should probably try building at least PyQt5 from source (I think Raspbian Stretch does not get updates anymore, although I'm not sure), unfortunately I do not quite have time for that at this moment, which is why I was hoping for a workaround, if someone encountered a similar problem ... But if worse comes to worse, I guess building the latest version from source is the only option left. Thanks again for the feedback!